# Print html and excel files with Print Service API

Tags: java, printing, java-7

I am using [java print service API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/JPSTOC.fm.html) to print documents (pdf, jpg, excel and html). I am able to print pdf and images but I am unable to print html and excel.

```
public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PrinterException {
    FileInputStream psStream = null;
    String filename = null; 
     filename = "I:/abc.html";
        psStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(psStream, psInFormat, null);  
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

    PrintService myPrinter = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    if (myPrinter != null) {            
        DocPrintJob job = myPrinter.createPrintJob();
        try {
        job.print(myDoc, aset);

        } catch (Exception pe) {pe.printStackTrace();}
    } else {
        System.out.println("no printer services found");
    }

}
```

}

I have searched on Internet and tried setting the Doc Flavor as:

```
DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE
```

But I am getting blank output.

Can I get some example on how to print excel and html using java print API?

Comment: I think you need to post some code here. For starters, how are you attempting to read the Excel files? There's no way Java can 'just know' how to print every file, which seems to be what you're expecting here...

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Done --